# Запись в CSV-файл

Tags: php, файлы

Как записать данные из массива в CSV-файл?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использовать специально предназначенную для этого функцию [fputcsv](http://ru.php.net/fputcsv)

```
<?php

$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array();
$hand = fopen("file.csv","w");
for($i=0;$i<=count($array);$i++)
{
fwrite($hand,$array[$i]);
}
fclose($hand);
```

Comment: если тут, то проще не for, а explode(). В смысле: взять массив, разбить элементы через запятую и записать в файл, добавив в конце EOL